# Python: issue with list elements comparision

Tags: python, list, comparison

The task is to define a function with argument x, where x is a list of integers.The function should print out the median value of items in it. My function always return None, I've tried to fix it, but after many tries I am out of ideas.
Code:

```
def median(x):
    x = sorted(x)
    med_val = 0
    if len(x) % 2.0 == 0:
        for i in x:
            if len(x[:i]) == len(x[i:]) + 1:
                return x[i]
    else:
        for i in x:
            if len(x[:i + 1]) == len(x[i: + 1]) + 1:
                return (x[i] + x[i + 1]) / 2
print (median([1, 4, 2, 6, 8]))
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: Currently you function returns None, because you never return anything.

Comment: yes, i have pasted the wrong code. I will change it in a moment

Comment: Why are you using a loop for finding median? Note that in Python 3.4+ you can now use [`statistics.median`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html#statistics.median).

Comment: I a begineer in coding tbh. This was the best idea I came up with

Answer (score 1):

In your method, replace the `print` statements by `return expression`. And in your function call, do:

```
print(median(list))
```

PS: It is better not to use `list` as a variable name in python.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```
def median(x):
    x = sorted(x)
    middle_index = float(len(x)/2.0) # this 2.0 part is very important
    if middle_index % 2 == 0: #check if it's even
        med_val = float((x[int(middle_index)]+x[int(middle_index-1)])/2) # take the average of the 2 middle values if so
    else: med_val = x[int(middle_index)] #otherwise, select the center value    

    return med_val #return median

lists = [[2, 1, 4, 6], [9,1,1,9,3], [1, 4, 2, 6, 8]]
for item in lists:
    print median(item) 

In:  [2, 1, 4, 6]
Out:  3.0
In:  [9, 1, 1, 9, 3]
Out:  3
In:  [1, 4, 2, 6, 8]
Out:  4
```